# Cannot understand control_fixed_ansatz in Qiskit VQLS implementation

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I've been studying the VQLS algorithm and came across this Qiskit implementation:
https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-applications/the-variational-quantum-linear-solver

I'm having trouble understanding the circuit in the “control_fixed_ansatz” function.

I know that we want to estimate the expectation of U^+A_nV(k) on the |0> state using the Hadamard test. So, I was expecting to find the controlled-version of the gates representing these matrices. However, in the ansatz, there are also ccx gates, and I'm not sure why they are used.

I would appreciate any help in understanding this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in the Qiksit tutorial that may have caused misunderstandings.

The function that builds the circuit to calculate the value <0|U^+ A_nV(k)|0> (so, after the  |<b|Psi>|^2) is the "special_had_test". The "control_fixed_ansatz" is a function that builds a circuit that applies the ansatz (with the appropriate parameters), but in a controlled way. This is used in the "special_had_test" where V(k), A_n and U need to be applied as controlled gates in the Hadamard Test to obtain the values <0|U^+ A_nV(k)|0>.

Therefore, the circuit in the "control_fixed_ansatz" is a controlled gate of the specific "apply_fixed_ansatz". I haven't done it, but you could test if the "control_fixed_ansatz" circuit applies the fixed ansatz, like the "apply_fixed_ansatz", on the corresponding qubits if the ancilla qubit is 1.